# How to return answers from Matlab function in form of Symbols

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to return an answer from Matlab in form of a symbolic variable.  I created the following code and function to illustrate the error I am receiving:

```
clc
clear all
syms L real;
% L = 1  % The code works when I uncomment this line
k1 = [ L,  -L;
      -L, 2*L]
k2 = [4*L^2, -L;
      0,      L]
K = GlobalStiffnessMatrix(k1,k2)
```

The m file GlobalStiffnessMatrix.m is shown below:

```
function K = GlobalStiffnessMatrix(k12,k23)
    K = zeros(2,2);
    K(1,1) = k12(1,1);
    K(1,2) = k12(1,2);
    K(2,1) = K(1,2);
    K(2,2) = k12(2,2) + k23(1,1);
end
```

I am receiving the following error:

> The following error occurred converting from sym to double:
>   Error using symengine (line 59)
>   DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.
>   If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use VPA.

I have tried to use VPA within the function itself and the simulation code but am still receiving the same error. Of course when I uncomment the line setting `L = 1` the function works fine and as expected.

How can I make this function return `K` as a symbolic variable?

Comment: You're initializing your output `K` as a double matrix using `zeros(2,2)`. Then you're trying to assign a symbolic variable to one of these elements and getting a type mismatch. Instead try initializing your output using `sym` like `K = sym('K', [2,2])`

Comment: beautiful! thanks that solved it!

Comment: No worries, I've added my comment as a full answer. Consider accepting it so that this question is closed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initialising a numerical matrix using

```
K = zeros(2,2);
```

Then trying to assign a symbolic variable to each of those numerical elements using

```
K(1,1) = k12(1,1);
```

Instead, initialise `K` as a symbolic 2x2 matrix using `sym` (see the documentation [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html)).

```
K = sym('K', [2,2]);
```

Now each element of `K` is a symbolic variable and you'll have no issues assigning each one to an existing symbolic variable.